# How to replicate the effects of scrollViewDidScroll when a scrollView is not scrolling

Tags: swift

I am using scrollViewDidScroll to trigger a function. It seems to trigger about 90 times a second when scrolling through a scroll view. When the scroll view stops scrolling I would like the function to still continue being executed. I currently have a timer with a time interval of 1 / 90th of a second that triggers the function. However, there is a delay between when the scrollViewDidScroll stops and the timer starts. How would I properly fire the function continuously?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.myScrollView.delegate = self
     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1 / 90, target: self, selector: #selector(tick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func tick(_ timer: Timer) {
     myFunction()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     myFunction()
}
```

Comment: That function is going to be called both when your timer fires AND when the scroll view scrolls.  If you want the function to fire at a regular interval whether the scrolling is occurring or not just use the time not both.

Comment: For some reason while scrolling the timer does not work. Then it resumes after the scrolling stops

Comment: That is because when using the scrolling on the main thread is blocking the timer.  You will have to create the timer manually and add it to the main run loop with this `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to run a function when the screen updates.

to do that you can use `CADisplayLink`

```
func createDisplayLink() {
    let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                    selector: #selector(step))
    
    displaylink.add(to: .current,
                    forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
}
     
func step(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
    print(displaylink.timestamp)
}
```

whit this there is no need to use `scrollViewDidScroll` .

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in trying it I was unable to get what I needed. Maybe I was just using it wrong. Upholder of truth's solution seemed to work for me though